# Access to Windows encryption from Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, encryption, ssl

This is a little complicated:

I'm working on a desktop application in Qt/C++ that needs to use SQLCipher, and that in turn needs access to encryption algorithms (the default is OpenSSL).  The "normal" thing to do would be to just grab OpenSSL and add it to my project, but for legal/import-export reasons that's not allowed.  (In theory, if a program shipped out of the US contains encryption technology it needs to be "blessed" by TPTB, that takes months we don't have, and our customer is a stickler for following the rules -- they have buildings full of attorneys.)

So I'd like to use the encryption facilities which I assume are installed natively on Windows (we can restrict to maybe XP or above, but can't require "server" or some such).

But I can't find a way to access the Windows-native encryption facilities.  I presume that we could probably reach them through the Visual stuff, but we're not using that.

Are there any "open" header files/glue modules that allow access to Windows encryption facilities?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar import/export issue in my work with OpenSSL and we decided to not ship OpenSSL libraries with our project. During installation of our software the user is asked to download OpenSSL from the Internet and install it. Then our installer verify that OpenSSL is installed correctly, and it continues with our software.

Our software isn't shipped with any cryptographic algorithm, so it could be exported without permission. Now it is the user's responsibility to gain permission to "import" OpenSSL from the Internet :).